# make certain lines of code ignored after something happens

Tags: python

in python, is there a way to make the computer skip over (without reading them) certain lines of code after a specific event happens, without using an if/while statement?

for example, i have a game that i would like to display a start-up screen on. once the screen is displayed and the user continues, i never need to display it again until the program is re-run.

i realise you can use an if statement to check if the screen has already displayed, but doing this 30+ times a second seems a bit inefficient to me, especially if i have multiple things i only need to do once in the program.

Comment: Probably you're thinking `Event based programming` in python. http://emptypage.jp/notes/pyevent.en.html

Comment: Checking a boolean flag in an if-statement *is* efficient. It can easily run millions times a second, and you wouldn't notice any slow down.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to Control Logic / Flow Control / Decision Statements. 
[This](http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/python-basics-understanding-the-flow-control-statements/) blog post would probably be useful.

Since you gave a hypothetical example of a game having a start-up / Splash screen, you would ideally be having a modular organization of your game code.

In that case you could have the 'start-up screen' in the initialization part of the game, which is run when the class is instantiated.

That being said, I would suggest taking a look at other open source games, and read the programming methodologies used. Here's a good start - https://github.com/justinmeister/Mario-Level-1

EDIT: Reading about [The State Pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) could possibly give you ideas.

Comment: 'In that case you could have the 'start-up screen' in the initialization part of the game, which is run when the class is instantiated.' what about other things, such as levels or a tutorial?

Comment: A series of if statements would be the accurate answer to your question; [Here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/the-often-underestimated-art-of-creating-an-awesome-in-game-tutorial--gamedev-5962)'s something related to your most recent comment.